How can I achieve that my app opens the new activies in another window/screen when I tap on a button?
I want to program an application which opens the activities in another windows/screens when I tap on a button and when I tap the recents button of the navigation bar I would like to see more screens/windows as like more application would be opened.
I want to see as many app icons as many activies are opened from my app.
I prefer the sample code in android kotlin but I would be happy in android java too.
Sorry for the bad description of my problem.
Please help me.
I tried intent flags to reach my goal but it isn't working.
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)


You need FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
val intent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)
startActivity(intent)

